# Searching for identical values in two arrays

Tags: arrays, search, find

I know this may seem trivial to most/all of you, but I've been scratching my head over this for some time now.

I want to find values in the first column (values in the first column of each array are 'years') of 2 separate arrays that are identical in size (2400 x 2). Once such values have been found, I am trying to store the corresponding values in column 2 of both arrays in a new array called z. My code is as follows:

```
n=1;

a_years=austrianAtmosphericTemperaturesTest(n,1);
r_years=frenchRainDataSimplified(n,1);

while n<=2400

    for a_years = r_years

        z=[frenchRainDataSimplified(n,1) austrianAtmosphericTemperaturesTest(n,2)  frenchRainDataSimplified(n,2)];

        n=n+1;

    end

end
```

I have tried other methods like `find` & `ismember` but I'm having no luck!

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: this is [tag:matlab] right? may be you forgot to tag it!

Comment: If it were me I'd break this up, so First I'd create a list which is the intersection of the year columns. Then I'd use that to go through one of the arrays and then look up in the other and set the cross references.